# Get current authorised user in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

How can I get current user in middleware? Laravel 5.6

When I try to include class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

and then

```
Auth::user()
```

I just get null

Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class DebugbarMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump(Auth::user()); echo "</pre>"; die();

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Authorization

```
$controller = new LoginController();
        $request = new Request();

        Auth::logout();

        $request->setLaravelSession(session()->driver(session()->getDefaultDriver()));

        $user = Auth::loginUsingId($id);

        if ($user) {
            $controller->authenticated($request, $user);
            return $this->sendResponse(['messages' => 'User authorization successfully'], 'M User authorization successfully');
        }

        return $this->sendError('User not found!');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785932/using-authuser-in-middleware

Comment: @Sohel0415 I don't have troubles with including class, but I tried to use guard, and got error Uncaught ReflectionException: Class auth.driver does not exist

Comment: And now I don't have any errors, just null $this->auth->user()

Comment: Is user already logged in?

Comment: Where do you have this middleware defined in the stack?

Comment: @Sohel0415 yes, user logged in

Comment: Are you using guard to log in?

Comment: @Devon didn't clearly understand your question. I defined it in Kernel.php in protected $middleware array

Comment: @Sohel0415 I think no

Comment: @TheWorldNode Can you share us your login and middleware code?

Comment: @Sohel0415 updated

Comment: @TheWorldNode why are you manually instantiating the controller and request?

Comment: @Devon I can't answer, because I didn't do it

Comment: @TheWorldNode show us what `dd(Auth::user())` gives after login in login function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global middleware stack runs prior to the session being started and authentication details being available.

Define this at the bottom of the 'web' group or in your route middleware.

Comment: Defined at the bottom of route middleware, but Auth::user() still NULL

Comment: Did you remove it from the global stack as indicated in your comment?  How did you verify you're authenticated and that Auth::user() is null?

Comment: When I remove it from global stack, my middleware doesn't executes. I understand, that I authorized, cause I tried to get Auth::user() in controller, there I get everything

Comment: Yes... that's the whole point of route middleware, you need to specify the routes you want the middleware to run on (either in the controller constructor or in the route definition), but route middleware will execute after the session has been started for web routes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I defined route with middleware in web routes and everything works perfect.